# Allow user to request resend of activation email

Tags: users, emails

I would like to code a way for a user to request the activation email be resent. Is there a function I can call from within a form-submit hook that will accomplish this?

(using Drupal 7)

Comment: you mean want the admin of the site to resend an activation email to a specific user?!

Comment: No. I would like to create a 'trouble logging in' page, where a unactive user can request the activation email to be resent based on email address

Answer (score 3):

First you need to create a custom form page using `hook_menu()` to allow users to enter their emails.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function custom_user_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user/trouble'] = array(
    'title' => 'trouble logging in',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('custom_user_trouble_logging_in_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Second, you need to create form structure

```
function custom_user_trouble_logging_in_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('E-Mail address'),
    '#size' => 60,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Resend activation email'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Third, validation step (check if user email already registered)

```
/*
 * Validation function
 */
function custom_user_trouble_logging_in_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $account = user_load_by_mail($form_state['values']['mail']);

  if(!$account) {
     form_error($form['mail'], t('Invalid user email'));
  }
}
```

Fourth, resend user activation email on form submission.

```
/*
 * Submit function for the 'Re-send welcome message'.
 */
function custom_user_trouble_logging_in_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $language;

  $destination = array();

  if (isset($_GET['destination'])) {
    $destination = drupal_get_destination();
    unset($_GET['destination']);
  }

  $account = user_load_by_mail($form_state['values']['mail']);
  $user_register = variable_get('user_register', 2);

  switch ($user_register) {
    case 0:
      $op = 'register_admin_created';
      break;
    case 1:
      $op = 'register_no_approval_required';
      break;
    case 2:
      $op = 'register_pending_approval';
      break;
  }

  $mail = _user_mail_notify($op, $account, $language);
  if (!empty($mail)) {
    watchdog('user', 'Welcome message has been re-sent to %name at %email.', array('%name' => isset($account->realname)? $account->realname : $account->name, '%email' => $account->mail));
    drupal_set_message(t('Welcome message has been re-sent to %name at %email', array('%name' => isset($account->realname)? $account->realname : $account->name, '%email' => $account->mail)));
  } else {
    watchdog('user', 'There was an error re-sending welcome message to %name at %email', array('%name' => isset($account->realname)? $account->realname : $account->name, '%email' => $account->mail));
    drupal_set_message(t('There was an error re-sending welcome message to %name at %email', array('%name' => isset($account->realname)? $account->realname : $account->name, '%email' => $account->mail)), 'error');
  }
  $form_state['redirect'] = $destination;
}
```

**Note:** `custom_user` is the name of the module that I used. You can change to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer will not work. [_user_mail_notify](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7) states that "By default, we always notify **except for canceled and blocked**.

Here is an implementation that notifies the user when they try to log in and sends them another email at that time using a custom user_mail_notify. "cgps_my_misc" is the name of a custom module.

```
<?php

function cgps_my_misc_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {

  switch ($form_id)  {
    case 'user_login_block':
          $form['#validate'][] = 'cgps_my_misc_user_login_name_validate';
          break;
  }
}

function cgps_my_misc_user_login_name_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['name']) && user_is_blocked($form_state['values']['name'])) {

    drupal_get_messages('error'); //Purges drupal core error message so we can set out own
    form_set_error('cgps_my_name', t('The account %name has not been activated.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['name'])));


    $user = user_load_by_name($form_state['values']['name']);


    $mail = cgps_my_misc_user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $user);

    if (!empty($mail)) {
      watchdog('user', 'Welcome message has been re-sent to %name at %email.', array('%name' => isset($user->realname)? $user->realname : $user->name, '%email' => $user->mail));
      drupal_set_message(t('Welcome message has been re-sent to %name at %email', array('%name' => isset($user->realname)? $user->realname : $user->name, '%email' => $user->mail)));
    } else {
      watchdog('user', 'There was an error re-sending welcome message to %name at %email', array('%name' => isset($user->realname)? $user->realname : $user->name, '%email' => $user->mail));
      drupal_set_message(t('There was an error re-sending welcome message to %name at %email', array('%name' => isset($user->realname)? $user->realname : $user->name, '%email' => $user->mail)), 'error');
    }
  }
}

function cgps_my_misc_user_mail_notify($op, $account, $language = NULL) {
    $params['account'] = $account;
    $language = $language ? $language : user_preferred_language($account);
    $mail = drupal_mail('user', $op, $account->mail, $language, $params);
  return empty($mail) ? NULL : $mail['result'];
}
```